# conditional substring in JS

Tags: javascript, substring

I have a function that should clean a string , actually I have two kind of string `"SATISFACTION._IS1.TOUTES_SITUATIONS.current_month_note"` or `"SATISFACTION._IS1.TOUTES_SITUATIONS.note"` .

**PS** *for information `TOUTES_SITUATIONS` is variable*

What I would return is `"TOUTES_SITUATIONS"`

Here's my code

```
const extractSituation: Function = (sentence: string): string => {
    return sentence.substring(
        sentence.lastIndexOf('1.') + 2,
        sentence.lastIndexOf('.n'),
    );
};
```

actually it handles only one type of sentence `"SATISFACTION._IS1.TOUTES_SITUATIONS.note"` but not `"SATISFACTION._IS1.TOUTES_SITUATIONS.current_month_note"`

How can I do to handle both of them ?

Comment: Will you always have periods in between each piece? If so, just use `split()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array's index start from 0. Try something like this:

```
const extractSituation: Function = (sentence: string): string => {
    return sentence.split('.')[2];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to just use a regex for this to pull out the text between the first `SATISFACTION._IS1.` and last `.`:

```js
let s = "SATISFACTION._IS1.TOUTES_SITUATIONS.current_month_note" 
let s2 = "SATISFACTION._IS1.TOUTES_someother.text__SITUATIONS.note" 

let regex = /^SATISFACTION._IS1\.(.*)\..*$/
console.log(s.match(regex)[1])
console.log(s2.match(regex)[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming:

1) You need to handle a general case where the 'situation' could be any string without periods.

2) The break before and after the 'situation' is delimited by '.'

You can retrieve the substring from the start of the situation to the end of the sentence, then find the index of the next '.' to find the substring containing only the situation.

```
const extractSituation: Function = (sentence: string): string => {
    // sentence truncated up to start of situation
    var situation = sentence.substring(sentence.lastIndexOf('1.') + 2);

    // Up to the next period from start of situation
    return situation.substring(0, situation.indexOf('.'));
};
```

This code only works given that you can assume every situation is preceded by your '1.' index.